# C# - Get Rendered html Code Using With Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I installed [WebDriver of Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) via NuGet package in a Console Application.
`Selenium.WebDriver v3.141.0`
Here is some sample code to request a web site with Internet Explorer, let it render and finally save the final HTML markup.

```
public class WebSiteHtmlLoader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly RemoteWebDriver _remoteWebDriver;

    public WebSiteHtmlLoader(RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver)
    {
        if (remoteWebDriver == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("remoteWebDriver");
        _remoteWebDriver = remoteWebDriver;
    }

    public string GetRenderedHtml(Uri webSiteUri)
    {
        if (webSiteUri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("webSiteUri");
        _remoteWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webSiteUri);

        return _remoteWebDriver.PageSource;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_remoteWebDriver != null)
            {
                _remoteWebDriver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!args.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var pageUrl = args.First();
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager
        };

        using (var htmlLoader = new WebSiteHtmlLoader(new InternetExplorerDriver(options)))
        {
            var html = htmlLoader.GetRenderedHtml(new Uri(pageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\htmlloadertext.html", html);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is these codes are depricated.
I also have error like this :

> The name 'InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy' does not exist in the
> current context

What is updated & workable codes for chrome or FireFox?

---

**Edit 1 :**
When i remove this line :

```
PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager
```

I got the error below :

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in
> WebDriver.dll

---

**Edit 2 :**
I have error after change those codes to use chrome instead of IE.
Here is the codes :

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pageUrl = "https://mempool.space";
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            //options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
            options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;
            using (var htmlLoader = new WebSiteHtmlLoader(new ChromeDriver(options)))
            {
                var html = htmlLoader.GetRenderedHtml(new Uri(pageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\htmlloadertext.html", html);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the error :

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in
> WebDriver.dll

Comment: Have you tried running it with no strategy, i.e. remove the line PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager or just PageLoadStrategy = 
 PageLoadStrategy.Eager

Comment: Have you tried running it with Chrome using Chrome options?  i.e. 
 var options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
 options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;

Comment: You will need to use "new ChromeDriver(options)" instead of "new InternetExplorerDriver(options)" to use the Chrome implementation

Comment: I did all your suggestions. Please see my `Edit 1` & `Edit 2`. Also this option does not exist for chrome : `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings`

Comment: This is true, that option does not apply to Chrome, can you see the debug console for the app?  I suspect that it is having trouble loading Chrome, have you made sure you have the latest versions of chrome and the latest versions of the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver packages?  It can be very picky when trying to start an instance of the browser when the versions don't match

Comment: I get the following when I run your code

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 63671
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample from above, I changed your Program.Main to

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!args.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var pageUrl = args.First();
        var options = new ChromeOptions()
        {
            PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager
        };

        using (var htmlLoader = new WebSiteHtmlLoader(new ChromeDriver(options)))
        {
            var html = htmlLoader.GetRenderedHtml(new Uri(pageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\htmlloadertext.html", html);
        }
    }
```

and it worked fine, the libs I am using are

```
  <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="92.0.4515.10700"/>
```

and you need to have v92 of Chrome installed on your PC.  I was able to extract https:\google.com to the specified file